# Creating a json object using jackson

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jackson

How can I create a json array like the example below using jackson.

I tried using ObjectMapper, but this does not seem correct.

```
      try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
            for (Path file : ds) {
                System.out.println("name:"+file.getFileName()+
                        "\n"+
                        "mime:"+Files.probeContentType(file)+
                "\n"+
                "locked:"+!Files.isWritable(file));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

Eventually I will be making a json that has the below values.

```
 * - (int)    size    file size in b. required
 * - (int)    ts      file modification time in unix time. required
 * - (string) mime    mimetype. required for folders, others - optionally
 * - (bool)   read    read permissions. required
 * - (bool)   write   write permissions. required
 * - (bool)   locked  is object locked. optionally
 * - (bool)   hidden  is object hidden. optionally
 * - (string) alias   for symlinks - link target path relative to root path. optionally
 * - (string) target  for symlinks - link target path. optionally
```

Here is an example json I was provided.

```
"files": [
    {
        "mime": "directory",
        "ts": 1334071677,
        "read": 1,
        "write": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "hash": "l1_Lw",
        "volumeid": "l1_",
        "name": "Demo",
        "locked": 1,
        "dirs": 1
    },
    {
        "mime": "directory",
        "ts": 1334071677,
        "read": 1,
        "write": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "hash": "l1_Lw",
        "volumeid": "l1_",
        "name": "Demo",
        "locked": 1,
        "dirs": 1
    },
    {
        "mime": "directory",
        "ts": 1340114567,
        "read": 0,
        "write": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "hash": "l1_QmFja3Vw",
        "name": "Backup",
        "phash": "l1_Lw",
        "locked": 1
    },
    {
        "mime": "directory",
        "ts": 1310252178,
        "read": 1,
        "write": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "hash": "l1_SW1hZ2Vz",
        "name": "Images",
        "phash": "l1_Lw",
        "locked": 1
    },
    {
        "mime": "application\/x-genesis-rom",
        "ts": 1310347586,
        "read": 1,
        "write": 0,
        "size": 3683,
        "hash": "l1_UkVBRE1FLm1k",
        "name": "README.md",
        "phash": "l1_Lw",
        "locked": 1
    }
]
```

EDIT 1

```
        Map<String, Object> filesMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Object> files = new ArrayList<Object>();
        System.out.println("\nNo filter applied:");
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
            for (Path file : ds) {
                Map<String, Object> fileInfo = new HashMap<>();
                fileInfo.put("name", file.getFileName().toString());
//                Prints Files in Director
//                Files.getAttribute(file,"size");
                System.out.println("name:" + file.getFileName().toString() +
                        "\n" +
                        "mime:" + Files.probeContentType(file) +
                        "\n" +
                        "locked:" + !Files.isWritable(file));
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(fileInfo);
                files.add(json);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        files.toArray();
        filesMap.put("files", files);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString;
        try {
            jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(filesMap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            jsonString = "fail";  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
```

Puts out the following json which is closer, but I can't figure out why the extra quotes before and after the {}.

```
{"files":["{\"name\":\"32C92124-EFCF-42C1-AFD2-8B741AE6854B.jpg\"}","{\"name\":\"58D5B83F-4065-4D6E-92BE-8181D99CB6CB.jpg\"}","{\"name\":\"7B1464A0-FBA1-429E-8A39-3DE5B539FBF8.jpg\"}","{\"name\":\"888159CF-45BE-475F-8C6A-64B3E1D97278.jpg\"}"]}
```

Final Answer

```
    Map<String, Object> filesMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<Object> files = new ArrayList<Object>();
    System.out.println("\nNo filter applied:");
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
        for (Path file : ds) {
            Map<String, Object> fileInfo = new HashMap<>();
            fileInfo.put("name", file.getFileName().toString());
            System.out.println("name:" + file.getFileName().toString() +
                    "\n" +
                    "mime:" + Files.probeContentType(file) +
                    "\n" +
                    "locked:" + !Files.isWritable(file));
            files.add(fileInfo);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    files.toArray();
    filesMap.put("files", files);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString;
    try {
        jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(filesMap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        jsonString = "fail"; 
    }
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing an actual question.

Comment: Sorry, with the plethora of internet issues I am having tonight I think I forgot to add that. :P  Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I am pretty confused.  There is no apparent use of `ObjectMapper` here.  Are you trying to convert something to use `ObjectMapper` or what?

Comment: You've shown your desired input and output, but nothing of what you have actually attempted re: actual conversion code. Have you read through the [Jackson in Five Minutes tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)?

Comment: I went through the tutorial and it is helping, not quite there yet, but getting close.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need a [`JsonNodeFactory`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory.html):

```
final JsonNodeFactory factory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
```

This class has methods to create `ArrayNode`s, `ObjectNode`s, `IntNode`s, `DecimalNode`s, `TextNode`s and whatnot. `ArrayNode`s and `ObjectNode`s have convenience mutation methods for adding directly most JSON primitive (non container) values without having to go through the factory (well, internally, they reference this factory, that is why).

As to an `ObjectMapper`, note that it is both a serializer (`ObjectWriter`) and deserializer (`ObjectReader`).

Comment: Actually going to bump this to be the answer since the other answer caused unforseen issues when I gave it credit.  This is the final answer that I used :)

Answer (score 16):

You can write an object to a json string. So I hope you have your data in an object of a class defined as per your need. Here is how you can convert that object into a json string:

```
//1. Convert Java object to JSON format
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

See [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/) for the full jackson-databind javadoc.

Comment: This got me pretty close, but for some reason I have extra quotes around the child objects.   I added what I have currently above.

Comment: @DirkLachowski Yep :)  I put it at the bottom of the description under the EDIT 1

Comment: The extra quotes was because I was using ObjectMapper twice. After removing the inner writeValueAsString I was able to get the result expected.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 15):

initializing JSON object as singleton instance, and building it:

```java
ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode(); // initializing
node.put("x", x); // building
```

PS: to println use `node.toString()`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this without creating POJO and converting it into JSON. I assume your data in the Record object.

```
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        ArrayNode childNodes = mapper.createArrayNode();
        for (Record record : records) {
            JsonNode element = mapper.createObjectNode();
            ((ObjectNode) element).put("mime": record.getDirectory());
                  //fill rest of fields which are needed similar to this.
                  //Also here record.getDirectory() method will should return "directory"
                  //according to your json file.
            childNodes.add(element);
        }
        ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("files", childNodes);
```